# Does drinking water at certain times help digestion, prevent high-blood pressure, strokes and heart-attacks?

Tags: medical-science, water

There is a poster in our breakroom at work that states this about drinking water:

> - 2 glasses of water in the morning helps internal organs
> - 1 glass before meal helps digestion
> - 1 glass before shower prevents high-blood pressure
> - 1 glass before bed helps prevent strokes or heart-attacks

I have had trouble finding evidence of any of these claims because the poster doesn't cite any sources and when I search myself I get mixed answers (not many peer-reviewed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This poster that you saw recalls from my memory a famous email I received once:

> HEART ATTACKS AND WATER !
>
> How many folks do you know who say they
>   don't want to drink anything before going to bed because they'll have
>   to get up during the night. . . . .
>
> *Very Important. From A Cardiac Specialist!*
>
> - Drinking water at a certain time maximizes its effectiveness on the body
> - **2 glasses of water after waking up - helps activate internal organs**
> - **1 glass of water 30 minutes before a meal helps digestion**
> - **1 glass of water before taking a bath - helps lower blood pressure**
> - **1 glass of water before going to bed - avoids stroke or heart attack**
>
> *Dr. Virend Somers is a cardiologist from the Mayo Clinic, who is lead
>   author of the report in the July 29, 2008 issue of the Journal of the
>   American College of Cardiology.*
>
> Most heart attacks occur in the day,
>   generally between 6 a.m. and noon. Having one during the night, when
>   the heart should be most at rest, means that something unusual
>   happened. Somers and his colleagues have been working for a decade to
>   show that sleep apnea is to blame.
>
> 1. If you take an aspirin or a baby aspirin once a day, take it at night. The reason: Aspirin has a 24-hour "half-life;" therefore, if
>      most heart attacks happen in the wee hours of the morning, the aspirin
>      would be strongest in your system.
> 2. FYI, aspirin lasts a really long time in your medicine chest, for years, (when it gets old, it smells like vinegar). . . . <sup>(1)</sup>

After this message has gone viral online: circulated on social media and people's emails; the Mayo Clinic, on behalf of Dr. Somers, exposed the falseness of this circulating email, and they said:

> Neither Dr. Somers nor Mayo Clinic contributed to this email, which
>   contains some information that is inaccurate and potentially harmful.
>   We recommend that you speak with your physician if you have specific
>   questions.<sup>(2)</sup>

This is an online hoax that you should immediately disregard.

<sup>(1) [What Bad Advice Did This Heart Attack Survivor Get?](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/09/24/online-myths_n_3954799.html) Huffington Post.  09/24/2013</sup>

<sup>(2) Misleading Aspirin Email. [Mayo Clinic News Network.](http://newsblog.mayoclinic.org/2010/02/28/misleading-aspirin-email-virend-somers-mayo-clinic/)  Feb 28, 2010</sup>

Comment: That's telling 'em!